# Why do I keep losing "consecutive days visited" on the main site?

Tags: support

I have GDSE in my "visit frequently" bookmarks. I am trying to earn the "Fanatic" badge, for visiting 100 days in a row. I KNOW I have made a point of being on the site every day. But my "consecutive days" keeps resetting; it was up to 70-something and now it's back to one! I was HERE on Friday. What gives? Does the site not register that I showed up unless I click on a question, even if I have the window open for ten minutes?

If this needs to be moved to some other SE mega overview site, by all means do so. :)

Comment: and what about loosing points suddenly, i was having 5300+ two days ago and today its 4180, I did not understand what happened suddenly anyone have any view on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to @Pearsonartphoto's comment about it being based on UTC (which often causes misses on weekends when you may not be on the same schedule as weekdays), you also have to visit an "internal" page every day.  Simply logging in or visiting the questions list won't do it.

*Update*
Found [the post where Jeff mentioned it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485) in response to somebody whose counter reset on Day 97 (ouch!):

> We see a login on 10-2 but no access to internal pages **(login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access")**.

<sup>*(Emphasis added)*</sup>

If you want to make certain to get it, the easiest way (in my humble opinion) is to vote on something every day.  Provides a value to the site and helps you badge-up in the process.

Answer (score 2):

The days are utc. So, if you went Thursday morning, and Friday late, you might have  missed a day. I don't recall what the criteria is for a visit, but 2 pages should be fine.

Comment: So I do have to click on something? The site does not register merely opening the window? I'll accept that I'm doing it wrong if that's the case.

Comment: I have the site in an open tab, and Firefox set to retain open tabs when it closes. That way I can just flip over to it and check for any new questions by refreshing the "Recent" page, and check Meta the same way. I missed one day when I was at Adobe MAX in October.